# Using "su - " to change user gives "No passwd entry for user"

Tags: linux, su, non-root-user, passwd, jenkins

Specifically, I am trying test something on my build server by switching to the "jenkins" user:

```
sudo su - jenkins
No passwd entry for user 'jenkins'
```

Comment: `adduser jenkins`

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks, yes, it looks like there is no jenkins user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message is pretty much self-explanatory. It says that the user `jenkins` has no entry in the `/etc/passwd` file i.e. the user does not exist in the system.

When you do any user related operations that requires username, password, home directory, shell information, the `/etc/passwd` file is consulted first. No entry in that file leading to the very error you are getting. So you need to create the user first (`useradd`/`adduser`). As a side note, unless necessary you should create any service specific user (non-human) e.g. `jenkins` as system user.

Comment: I would argue that it is not self-explanatory. The error is about a password and the problem is the non existence of a user. If the error was the user does not exist that would be self-explanatory.

Comment: @YannickSSE the error message is not about password, it is about *passwd* which is the traditional database of user accounts on a system (residing in `/etc/passwd`). On most modern systems, the passwords as such are stored elsewhere - often in `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: You can force it with `su -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Answer (score 4):

After a quick search for "List all users in Linux", I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/410274/333604) and ran the following command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

and, As @Ipor Sircer, suggested, this user does not actually exist, and I have to add it with:

```
adduser jenkins
```

Comment: Did it resolved your issue? Does creating a `jenkins` user by yourself is same as the user created by jenkins itself?